# Greatest n per group while also returning content

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have looked at other answers but am having trouble applying the answers to my application. I have a query that returns something like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE T;

__________________________________________________________
|  ID  | AORB |      ....OTHER (UNIQUE) CONTENT.....      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  1   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  2   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  3   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  3   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  4   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  5   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  6   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  6   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, there are occasionally a maximum of two rows with the **same ID** but different content and an `AORB` of either A or B. Sometimes there are "unique" ID's with a count of one and `AORB` could either be `A` or `B`.

Just to make the data structure clear, you could split the table up by filtering on 'AORB' as follows:

All A's:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'A';

__________________________________________________________
|  ID  | AORB |      ....OTHER (UNIQUE) CONTENT.....      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  2   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  3   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  4   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  6   |   A  |      ....CONTENT                          |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

All B's:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'B';

__________________________________________________________
|  ID  | AORB |      ....OTHER (UNIQUE) CONTENT.....      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  3   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  5   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
|  6   |   B  |      ....CONTENT                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that would be similar to the following but **return all the other content rows** to the right:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(AORB) 
FROM MYTABLE T
GROUPBY ID;
```

My requirement is that if there are two rows with the same id, return the row with `AORB` of `A`. If there is only one row for a given id, return that row, regardless of `AORB`.

I've tried doing a UNION of both the a and b queries but since the content is different, it still returns "duplicate" ID's:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'B'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT T.* 
FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.AORB = 'B' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE T2 WHERE T2.ID = T.ID AND T2.AORB = 'A');
```

This is a prioritization query.  It returns all "A"s.  And then all "B"s if there is no corresponding "A".

Comment: This is really great, its exactly what I needed. I replaced `MYTABLE` with a `WITH` since my actual query is much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number` prioritizing the conditions in `order by`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN T.AORB = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS RNUM
FROM MYTABLE T
) T
WHERE RNUM=1
```

If the AORB values are only A,B the query can be simplified to

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY T.AORB) AS RNUM
FROM MYTABLE T
) T
WHERE RNUM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for variety, here's another way to do it:

```
with mins as (
    select id, min(aorb) as min_aorb
    from mytable
    )
select t.*
from mytable t
    inner join mins on mins.id=t.id and mins.min_aorb=t.aorb;
```

This avoids having to code 'A' and 'B' directly into the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, min(aorb) as min_aorb,
       min(content) keep (dense_rank first order by aorb) as content
from   ...
group by id
```

will give you the answer in one pass over the data (saving a lot of I/O compared to most of the other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

I voted for vkp's answer, as it will be more likely to get what you need as long as AORB is alphabetic. I'm not a fan of hard-coding a condition if it's not needed. I also think that AORB should have a different name. Today, the possible values are A and B, but from experience, I can tell you that someone will eventually add a C, D, E or 9. Then you'll have to go back and recode the UNION/EXISTS logic because extras will show up. As long as AORB stays in the collated order that you need, the ROW_NUMBER() method will work. I'd also caution that if the database collation changes, it will alter your results.

To see collation effects:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#myStuff', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #myStuff ; 

CREATE TABLE #myStuff ( 
    ID int
    , AORB char(1) /* Watch collation. This is case-sensitive */ collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
    , otherContent varchar(120) 
) ;
INSERT INTO #myStuff (ID, AORB, otherContent)
VALUES 
      (1,'a','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.')
    , (1,'A','Nulla malesuada tellus a arcu ultrices suscipit.')
    , (1,'B','Proin lacinia laoreet pretium.') 
    , (2,'a','Nam commodo, elit sit amet efficitur rutrum, nisi magna semper neque, vitae fermentum nulla erat a felis.')
    , (3,'A','Vivamus eget augue in felis luctus gravida congue et lectus.')
    , (3,'B','Phasellus ullamcorper vehicula ornare.')
    , (4,'A','Vivamus in facilisis nisl.')
    , (5,'B','Duis accumsan elit nisi, eu sodales metus fermentum ut.')
    , (6,'D','Aenean ultrices suscipit dui sit amet mollis.')
    , (6,'C','Maecenas feugiat, ligula et tristique venenatis, lectus lorem ornare dui, id convallis felis sapien non justo.')
    , (7,'A','Suspendisse vitae mattis leo.')
    , (7,'9','Nam eu nunc tincidunt, hendrerit elit at, semper diam.')
    , (7,'a','Quisque ornare erat justo, id venenatis est congue eu. ')
;

SELECT t2.id, t2.AORB, t2.otherContent, rn
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.AORB, t1.otherContent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.AORB) AS rn
    FROM #myStuff t1
) t2
WHERE t2.rn=1
;

SELECT t2.id, t2.AORB, t2.otherContent, rn
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.AORB, t1.otherContent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.AORB) AS rn
    FROM #myStuff t1
) t2
WHERE t2.rn=1
;
```

That's the collation for case-sensitive latin. Default SQL is usually case-insensitive.